# Multi-table group Insert for copying procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, parallel-processing, insert

I am working on a procedure that copies one database to another. I am having trouble with a a group/parallel insertion feature for certain tables.

I have figured out insertion sequentially.

```
FOR...LOOP
   insert /*+ enable_parallel_dml parallel */ into new_table select * from old_table
   commit;
END LOOP;
```

I want to insert some tables simultaneously so I tried.

```
FOR...LOOP
   INSERT ALL
     /*+ enable_parallel_dml parallel */ into new_table1 select * from old_table1
     /*+ enable_parallel_dml parallel */ into new_table2 select * from old_table2
     /*+ enable_parallel_dml parallel */ into new_table3 select * from old_table3
   select * from dual;
     commit;
END LOOP;
```

But this does not work...any ideas how to tackle this?